# c# не получается удалить базу данных после работы с ней

Tags: c#, sql

```
using (SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + @"C:\db" + ";Version=3;"))
{
    db.Open();
    SQLiteCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM moz_cookies";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) while (reader.Read()) if (Convert.ToString(reader["baseDomain"]) == dm)
    {
        lst.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["name"]));
        lst.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["value"]));
    };
    db.Close();
}
File.Delete(@"C:\db");
```

Ошибка, что "C:\db" используется другим процессом

Comment: попробуйте вызвать `GC.Collect();` и `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` перед удалением файлика

Comment: @tym32167 Не помогло. Пока исполняемый EXE открыт, файл вручную даже не удалить

Comment: можно попробовать ещё [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24570408/312041)

Answer (score 1):

SQLiteCommand cmd нужно было тоже в using обернуть... Тогда все работает